# I Want to display only two row one is header and other dropdown selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
when I select a country from dropdown list then press find button it will display value into a table format and when I select another country first will replace by other value
[enter image description here][1] 
[enter image description here][2]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uXic.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR6HM.jpg
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<select id="data">
  <option value="#">Select a country ..</option>
  <option value="us">United States</option>
  <option value="es">Spain</option>
 <!-- more countries -->
</select>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td> Country </td>
  <td> Chance</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hideShowTr" id="us"  style="display: none;">
  <td> United States </td>
  <td> 2.02 % </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hideShowTr" id="es" style="display: none;">
  <td> Spain </td>
  <td> 2.12 % </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
$('#data').change(function() {
    $('tr#' + $(this).val()).css('display','block');
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>

this is the code I try but not work
```

when I select a country from dropdown list then press find button it will display value into a table format and when I select another country first will replace by other value

Comment: How can you determine if a filter by Country would work if every row has the same text in the Country field?

Comment: Do u want to do in javascript or any other backend languages?

Comment: hi https://jsfiddle.net/s5c328b1/ is this what you are looking for ?